# Capture onTap on WebView

Tags: flutter

Consider the following fragment:

```
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTapUp: (details) => print('webview tapped $details'),
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
```

I'd like to capture tap events on the WebView and avoid them to be executed in the WebView. I want to evaluate the tap events myself. However, panning/scaling events should still be handled by the WebView.

However, the code above does basically nothing. The WebView still gets and executes all tap events.

Comment: Is it necessary to handle the tap events yourself or just prevent the webview from reacting to tap events?

Comment: Let me clarify in the question.

Comment: So you exclusively want to disable detect taps without disabling anything else?

Comment: Exactly. I want the WebView to handle panning etc, but tapping should be handled by my GestureDector and ignored by the WebView.

Comment: Why are you using the `onTapUp` parameter?

Comment: I'd like to know where the user clicked on the WebView.

Comment: Use `onTap`. By default, the web view will only handle pointer events for gestures that were not claimed by any other gesture recognizer. You're not claiming the *whole* tap for your `GestureDetector`, so some is still getting through.

Comment: Tried that already, Doesn‘t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the riddle. The solution is:

```
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTapDown: (_) => print('webview onTapDown $_'),
            onTapUp: (_) => print('webview onTapUp $_'),
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

The explanation is quite simple:

Flutter sweeps the gesture arena at pointer up and the first gesture recognizer wins. In the fragment from the question, the WebView itself is the first gesture recognizer and the GestureDetector is the second (children first order).

By laying out a stack with a translucent overlay, the overlay becomes the first recognizer and the WebView the second. So, when the arena is swept, the custom GestureDetector wins.

Comment: Not working for me, Not able to get focus on the webview. Is there any other way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score -1):

use
[gestureRecognizers](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebView/gestureRecognizers.html) property with [TapGestureRecognizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/TapGestureRecognizer-class.html) like below example

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: someUrl,
  gestureRecognizers: Set()
    ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(
      () => TapGestureRecognizer())),
)
```

Or, written another way:

```
var verticalGestures = Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(
  () => TapGestureRecognizer());
var gestureSet = Set.from([verticalGestures]);
return WebView(
  initialUrl: someUrl,
  gestureRecognizers: gestureSet,
);
```